# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/cars/1/consumptions/new"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this routing error when I add a consumption (after submit it fails) and I am stuck, What am I doing wrong?

A user can have several cars and for each of his car he wants to look after his gas consumptions.

I have three active record models

```
create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "car_name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "consumption_searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "consumptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "total_price"
    t.float "kilometers"
    t.string "shop"
    t.float "liter_price"
    t.float "total_liters"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "car_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

- car `belongs_to :users` and `has_many :consumptions`
- user `has_many :cars`, and `has_many :consumptions through: :cars`
- consumption `belong_to :car` and `belongs_to :user`

My create method in **consumptions_controller.rb**

```
def create 
    @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
    @consumption = Consumptions.new(consumption_params)
    @consumption.car = @car
  if @consumption.save!
    redirect_to car_consumptions_path, notice: 'consumption was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

**cars_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    @search = ConsumptionSearch.new(params[:search])
    @consumptions = @search.date_range
    @consumptions = @consumptions.order('created_at ASC').where(car_id: @car.id)
end
```

**views/consumptions/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for car_consumptions_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
    root to: "cars#index"

    resources :cars do
        resources :consumptions
    end
end
```

**rails routes | grep consumption**

```
  car_consumptions GET    /cars/:car_id/consumptions(.:format)                                                     consumptions#index
                          POST   /cars/:car_id/consumptions(.:format)                                                     consumptions#create
      new_car_consumption GET    /cars/:car_id/consumptions/new(.:format)                                                 consumptions#new
     edit_car_consumption GET    /cars/:car_id/consumptions/:id/edit(.:format)                                            consumptions#edit
          car_consumption GET    /cars/:car_id/consumptions/:id(.:format)                                                 consumptions#show
                          PATCH  /cars/:car_id/consumptions/:id(.:format)                                                 consumptions#update
                          PUT    /cars/:car_id/consumptions/:id(.:format)                                                 consumptions#update
                          DELETE /cars/:car_id/consumptions/:id(.:format)                                                 consumptions#destroy
```

As requested
[image]

#### EDIT

here is what I have in the HTML if it can help:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form /cars/1/consumptions" action="/cars/1/consumptions/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="0nwq/pQSXCU2ptBjbewTCBffPLpZZUPAj6/HPQTGtYd8cHz9zv8R/C/JYnXPDpKw5o3/vGlVtav2Sa2nSvgOQdQ==">
```

Comment: What's the exact line that shows the error (show the full stacktrace)? because the error points to a "new" action but you are not using `new_car_consumption` anywhere. The error says that, somewhere, you are trying to point to `new_car_consumption` using method POST which is not right, it should be GET.

Comment: updated, it's after submiting the new consumption

Comment: `car_consumptions_path` is missing a `car_id` on both places you use it, also `simple_form_for` expect the first parameter to be an object and you are passing a helper, it should be something like: `simple_form_for [@consumption, @car]` for nested resources. You are still not showing the full error stacktrace (at least file name and line number)

Comment: The picture of the error page is not showing the stacktrace of the error. Click on Full Trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the controller

```
# GET /cars/:car_id/consumptions/new
def new
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  @consumption = @car.consumptions.new
end

# POST /cars/:car_id/consumptions
def create 
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  @consumption = @car.consumptions.new(consumption_params)
  # `.save!` will raise an exception and blow up if the record is invalid. 
  # Not good.
  if @consumption.save
    redirect_to car_consumptions_path(@car), notice: 'consumption was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Note the redirect:

```
# consumptions#index
redirect_to car_consumptions_path(@car), notice: 'consumption was successfully created.'
```

Since this is a nested route you need to provide the `car_id` segment.

You could also redirect to:

```
# consumptions#show
redirect_to [@car, @consumption], notice: 'consumption was successfully created.'
# or to cars#show
redirect_to @car, notice: 'consumption was successfully created.'
```

When using `simple_form_for` you pass it model instances that it binds the form to. When creating forms for nested routes you should pass an array:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@car, @consumption]) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

This uses the [polymorphic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) to find the correct path. You can use this same signature for `link_to`, `redirect_to`, `url_for` and `path_for`.

When declaring nested routes you should consider [using the `shallow` option](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting). It will only nest the collection routes (new, create, index) and not the member routes.

Comment: Many thanks I could figure before finding your reply that I was missing  `@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])`in the new action.
Your help was really precious for the redirection !
+ 10

Comment: @max I'm not sure you can call `new` on the association, there's a `build` method for that.

Comment: @arieljuod .build is just an alias for .new

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <%= form_for [@cars, @consumptions] do |form| %>
      ...
  <% end %>
```

or

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @cars, @consumptions ]) do |form| %>
```

*** Update:

```
resources :cars, shallow: true do
    resources :consumptions
end
```

Into form:

```
<% = simple_form_for [@car, @consumption] do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing your `new` action, but I assume you are setting a `@car` and a `@consumption = @car.consumptions.build` variables.

Try with this:

```
simple_form_for @consumption, url: url_for(controller: :consumptions, action: :create, car_id: @car.id) do |f|
```

It should work with `simple_form_for [@car, @consumption] do |f|` but you said "it doesn't work" which is too ambiguous (how does that not work? same error? new error? you should be more clear when responding to answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
 car_consumptions_path != car_consumption_path
```

I don't see any "car_consumptions" in your routes.

Comment: I changed to `car_consumption_path`
No route matches {:action=>"show", :car_id=>"1", :controller=>"consumptions"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: but there  are:
 car_consumptions GET    /cars/:car_id/consumptions(.:format)                                                     consumptions#index
                          POST   /cars/:car_id/consumptions(.:format)

Comment: I guess you need:  car_consumption_path(car, consumption) because you need both ":id" parts.

Comment: it does  not do the job :(